# How to duplicate an array vertically and horizontally in C?

Tags: c, arrays, copy

Say I have a 3x1 vertical array consisting of these 3 letters:

- a
- b
- c

Given a new height per row (2) and width (3), I would like to create a new array that looks like the following:

- a a a
- a a a
- b b b
- b b b
- c c c
- c c c

I'm thinking of using a double for loop, with the rows going from 0 to height times the number of variables, and the width going from 0 to width, but I'm not sure how to keep track of how many rows I already have for each letter.

Comment: You could do it with three `for` loops. The outer loop counts the letters (3), the middle loop counts the new height (2), and the inner loop counts the width (3)

Comment: You can do it in one loop, but I would not recommend it: `void DoIt(size_t R, size_t C, size_t H, size_t W, int D[R*H][C*W], const int S[R][C]) { size_t size = sizeof S[0][0]; char *d = (char *) D; const char *s = (const char *) S; for (size_t i = 0; i < R*H*C*W * size; ++i) { size_t b = i % size; size_t c = i/size % (W*C) / W; size_t r = i / (size*W*C*H); d[i] = s[(r*C + c)*size + b]; } }`. `R` and `C` are the source dimensions, `H` and `W` are the replications factors for height and width, `D` is the destination array, and `S` is the source array.

Comment: thanks both of you guys, I managed to do it with the 3 for loops